# How to implenet a timed loop in a Matlab function block

Tags: matlab, function, loops, block, simulink

I'm very new to Matlab Simulink and I'm trying to implement a loop in the Matlab Function Block that goes on non-stop during the whole simulation.
Input:

"t" from a simple clock to make it go on until the simulation lasts.

"v" and "i" what gives a specific "p*" value, by changing the ouptut "D" a little bit I want to check if this "p*" value gets bigger or smaller (in the whole model "v" and "i" are influenced by "D")

```
function D = fcn(v,i,t)
%#codegen
p1 = v*i;
D = 0.5;
D = D + 0.05;

while t > 0

p2 = v*i;

if p1 > p2 
  D = D - 0.05;

else
  D = D + 0.05;

end;

p1 = p2;

end;
```

The Function Block says it is correct, but as I start to run it, it freezes. The next step I wanted to do (but never got there) is to put a little timer in it, to execute this loop lets say every 0.01 sec or something. Is that compliable with a Matlab Function Block or is there any way achieving this?

Comment: There no break, no T incrementation ?

Comment: have you considered the `If-action subsystem` block and the `While iterator subsystem` blocks? They are very convenient to use.

Comment: You're freezing because you have an infinite loop.  At the first simulation time step when t > 0, when this block is called, it will never exit the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want do do `if t > 0` instead of `while t > 0`. Simulink already has the timer loop and it will call your function `fcn` at each time step `t`. You do not want to start your own loop inside that.